# Replacing overlapping matches in a string (regex or string operations)

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying to find all occurrences of a substring in a given string, and replace a specific occurrence with another substring (the condition is not important for the question).
What I need is to find all occurrences (even overlapping ones) and to be able to easily replace a specific one I choose.

The issue is that if I don't use lookahead I can't find overlapping occurrences (e.g. find "aa" in "aaa" will only find the first "aa" sequence because the second one overlaps with the first one):

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("aa"));
regex.Matches("aaa").Count;
```

**Value of the second line:** 1
**Expected:** 2

If I use a lookahead I find all of the occurrences but the replacement doesn't work (e.g. replace "a" in "a" with "b", will result in "ba" instead of "b"):

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("(?=a)"));
regex.Replace("a", "b");
```

**Replace result:** ba
**Expected:** b

Those are, of course, simple examples that showcase the issues in an easy way, but I need this to work on any example.
I know that I can easily do a search for both, or manually go over the word, but this code snippet is going to run many times and needs to both be efficient and readable.

Any ideas / tips on finding overlapping occurrences while still being able to replace properly? Should I even be using regex?

Comment: Can you provide some more simple examples with expected results. If your input is "aaa" and you want to replace "aa" with "b", what should the result look like?

Comment: Depending on the occurrence that I want to replace.
This is something I do behind the scene to make sure that the regex replaces the right occurrence, but I can't find all of the occurrences and that's my issue...
The code that chooses the right occurrence is long and it doesn't rely on the regex itself, it just needs access to all of the possible occurrences

Comment: hm i'm not sure if overlapping is possible, but you can search for `aa` and `(?<=a)aa` and combine the results.

Comment: The issue with that is that I won't only have a sequence of "a"'s, I might have more complex substrings

Comment: I would forgo using regex in this case and write a simple loop using substring to find all the occurrences.

Comment: Thanks! May you explain to me why this is a better option?

Comment: Is it not possible to just replace `a` with your substring?

Comment: I can't say this would be the better option for everyone, but I would find it more understandable to solve this problem than using regex. From past experience I think it would be faster than a regex solution also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would forgo regex and write a simple loop as below (there is room for improvement), because I think it would be quicker and more understandable.

```
        public IEnumerable<int> FindStartingOccurrences(string input, string pattern)
        {
            var occurrences = new List<int>();

            for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (input.Length+1 > i+pattern.Length)
                {
                    if (input.Substring(i, pattern.Length) == pattern)
                    {
                        occurrences.Add(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            return occurrences;
        }
```

and then call like:

`var occurrences = FindStartingOccurrences("aaabbaaaaaccaadaaa", "aa");`

Comment: I'll try both solutions (or at least a variation of them that fits my code) and choose the answer that will be more helpful in that case (I need to test for performance to make sure).
Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I have tried multiple different solutions:  
1. Multiple Regex methods  
2. Moore-Bayer algorithm
3. this  
And your solution, combined with a generator, was faster than the rest by a lot (around 10 times faster on average!) for my purposes. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To get overlapping results you have to shift your search pattern by one char for as many times as your search string is long.

Let's say for a text containing `aaaaaa` and a seachrstring of `aaa` (4 expected matches), three regex searches will be done with the search patterns:

- `aaa` (2 Matches)
- `(?<=a)aaa` (1 Match)
- `(?<=aa)aaa` (1 Match)

Same works for more complex searches like `aba` in `abababa`.

```
private static IEnumerable<Match> GetOverlappingMatches(string text, string searchstring)
{
    IEnumerable<Match> combinedMatches = Enumerable.Empty<Match>();

    for (int i = 0; i < searchstring.Length; i++)
    {
        combinedMatches = combinedMatches.Concat(GetMatches(text, searchstring, i));
    }

    return combinedMatches.Distinct(new MatchComparer());
}

private static IEnumerable<Match> GetMatches(string text, string searchstring, int shifts)
{
    string lookahead = $"(?<={searchstring.Substring(0, shifts)})";
    string pattern = $"{lookahead}{searchstring}";
    return Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
}
```

You also want to add a `MatchComparer` to filter double matches.

```
public class MatchComparer : IEqualityComparer<Match>
{
    public bool Equals(Match x, Match y)
    {
        return x.Index == y.Index
            && x.Length == y.Length;
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Match obj)
    {
        return obj.Index ^ obj.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I still think a simple loop would be faster and make more sense.

Comment: Very interesting and well written, this solution is elegant looks wise, but might be really expensive. Will test for performance and inform you both. Thanks a lot!